# remove duplicate error from JSON value React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am trying to pass filtered value from JSON to the parent component, however I've tried using [`Set`](https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-remove-array-duplicates-in-es6-50f6) but seems the output is still the same. The component that I'm using to render the JSON is picker from `native-base`. I want to filter out the repeated value in my picker. Greatly appreciated if anyone can help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27QdQ.png)

Here's my code.

```
Picker.js

const DefaultPicker = ({labelItem, pickerWidth, onHandleValue, ...rest}) => {
  const context = useContext(WindowContext);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('-Select-');
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

  function onNewData() {
    if (user) {
      user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
        Axios.get('URL_ENDPOINT', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer' + idToken,
          },
        })
          .then(({data}) => {
            setData(data.features);
            // console.log(data.features);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const form = onNewData(onNewData);
    return form;
  }, []);

  return (
        <PickerWrapper>
          <PickerItem
            width={pickerWidth}
            height="60"
            mode="dropdown"
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
              setSelectedValue({itemValue});
            }}>
            {Array.from(
              new Set(
                data.map((value, index) => (
                  <PickerItem.Item
                    key={index}
                    label={value.properties[labelItem]}
                    value={value.properties[labelItem]}
                    {...rest}
                  />
                )),
              ),
            )}
          </PickerItem>
        </PickerWrapper>
  );
};
```

And here is my parent component

```
SiteData.js

const SiteData = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const onHandleValue = (params) => {
    setValues(params);
    console.log(params);
  };
  return (
    <ScrollableView>
      <DetailContainer>
        <DetailWrapper>
          <DetailTitle>Site Data</DetailTitle>
          <DetailSubtitle marginTop="10">
            Insert new data found during your audit or observation session
          </DetailSubtitle>
          <DetailSubcontainer>
            <DefaultPicker
              labelItem={'category'} <-- receive value from child
              pickerWidth="100%"
              onHandleValue={onHandleValue}
            />
          </DetailSubcontainer>
        </DetailWrapper>
      </DetailContainer>
    </ScrollableView>
  );
};
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I'm using the filter() method so i can create a new array but it returns only one value in the picker list.

```
const indexData = data.filter(
    ({category}, index) => {
      return (
        data.findIndex(
          (item) =>
            item.category === category,
        ) === index
      );
    },
  );
```

The output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oygc4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code by adding this on child component

```
var setObj = new Set();

var result = data.reduce((acc,item)=>{
  if(!setObj.has(item.category)){
    setObj.add(item.category,item)
    acc.push(item)
  }
  return acc;
},[]);
```